# how to get the guid element of this array

Tags: php, wordpress

```
Array (
 [330] => WP_Post Object (
    [ID] => 330
    [post_author] => 1
    [post_date] => 2019-02-01 21:01:54
    [post_date_gmt] => 2019-02-01 21:01:54
    [post_content] => 
    [post_title] => wordpress-4.9.8
    [post_excerpt] => 
    [post_status] => inherit 
    [comment_status] => open 
    [ping_status] => closed 
    [post_password] => 
    [post_name] => wordpress-4-9-8 
    [to_ping] => 
    [pinged] => 
    [post_modified] => 2019-02-01 21:01:54 
    [post_modified_gmt] => 2019-02-01 21:01:54 
    [post_content_filtered] => 
    [post_parent] => 329 
    [guid] => http://localhost:8080/brainwise/wp-content/uploads2019/02/wordpress-4.9.8.zip 
    [menu_order] => 0 
    [post_type] => attachment 
    [post_mime_type] => application/zip 
    [comment_count] => 0 
    [filter] => raw
    ) 
)
```

I am using WordPress and I have the following Object Array from my post table and I want to extract `guid` element of this array.
How do I extract this?

Comment: It's not an array, it's an object inside an array. Use `->` to access the object property.

Comment: i know that its inside the object    i got it that way: echo $children['330']->{guid}; and i got this array after print_r($children);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the key then the object inside it

```
                  <p>echo $array_name[array_keys($array_name)[0]]->{guid};</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `get_the_guid( $post->ID );`.

See: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_guid/